# Elementary OS freezes while watching Video or when connecting to a SMB server

Tags: crash

So I installed Elementary OS and its really great, but I have a big issue with it.

The whole system crashes or freezes (no cursor movement or ctrl + alt + f1) when watching video with the "Video" application or when I try to connect to my SMB server. Before that I had issue with shutdown/hibernate/restart, so I searched around and deleted the "quite splash" part in the GRUB, which helped with the shutdown/hibernate/restart problem.

Here is the output for dmesg: http://pastebin.com/Hrk1ydmX

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the problem by disabling the USB 3.0 support in the notebook's BIOS.

Note: This also made the "quite splash" edit obsolete.

Comment: How does USB affect internal DVD player? I have in my computer internal slot for DVDs and every time I run it, it works for some time and then suddenly freezes computer.

Disabling USB 3.0 doesn't solve it :<

I've checked DVDs playing with Videos app and VLC - it freezes in both apps

Comment: can you make this as answered please